# When given a pair of ints, I need my code to be able to return the int that is closest to 21 without going over

Tags: java, methods, integer

```
// blackjack(7,17) -> 17  
// blackjack(21, 16) -> 21  
// blackjack(19,23) -> 19  

public int blackjack(int a, int b) {

}
```

After this I am really unsure of how to go about writing this code.

Comment: Please make an effort to solve this yourself. If you fail, post the code you've tried and perhaps we can help you.

Comment: ... I don't even know where to begin, that's why I don't have anything to show for it.

Comment: what happens if a)they are the same (e.g., `blackjack(16, 16);`) or are both over 21 (e.g., `blackjack(23, 22);`). In addition to not demonstrating effort, the problem is underspecified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi use this code.

```
if(a<=21 && b<=21){
    return Math.max(a, b);
}
```

This is a easy problem, try yourself next time.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case of either `a` or `b` being over 21.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
private int blackjack(int a, int b)
{
    int aa = 21-a >= 0 ? 21-a : 22;
    int bb = 21-b >= 0 ? 21-b : 22;

    if ( aa > 21 && bb > 21 )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return aa < bb ? a : b;
}
```