# Is There a More Efficient Java 8 Stream approach for finding the index in an int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Based upon a [BlackJack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848371/when-given-a-pair-of-ints-i-need-my-code-to-be-able-to-return-the-int-that-is-c#36848371), I got to wondering about how to indicate all of the winning hands. The original question simply asked, in effect, about the maximum of two numbers not greater than 21. So a method like

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b);
```

However, what if one wished to return all of the winning hands (assuming the location in the input array was a seat at a table), so a signature such as:

```
/**
 * returns an array indicate the index in the specified hands that
 * correspond to the winning locations. Will return an empty array if
 * there are no winners. The length of the returned array is how many
 * winning hands there were
 * @param hands The total for each hand, where the index is the seat
 * @return the index/"seat" where a winning hand was found; may return
 *    an empty array
 */
public int[] blackjack(int[] hands) { ... }
```

So based upon input data such as (just using 3 "players" at "seats" 0, 1, 2):

> { 17, 15, 23 }
>   { 23, 25, 22 }
>   {18, 16, 18 }
>   {16, 21, 20}

I would expect output along the lines of:

> Hands: [17, 15, 23]  has winners at [0]
>   Hands: [23, 25, 22]  has no winners
>   Hands: [18, 16, 18]  has winners at [0, 2]
>   Hands: [16, 21, 20]  has winners at [1]

In times past, I would have iterated the `hands[]` array, found the maximum that was <= 21, and then iterated again finding each index that was equal to the maximum. So something like this:

```
public static int[] blackjackByIteration(int[] hands)
{
    int max = 0;
    int numAtMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hands.length; ++i) {
        if (hands[i] <= 21 && hands[i] > max) {
            max = hands[i];
            numAtMax = 1;
        }
        else if (hands[i] == max) {
            ++numAtMax;
        }
    }

    int[] winningSeats = new int[numAtMax];

    int loc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hands.length; ++i) {
        if (hands[i] == max) {
            winningSeats[loc++] = i;
        }
    }

    return winningSeats;
}
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to implement it via streams. I am cognizant that [using Lambdas is not the solution to all problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179001/find-all-the-indexes-of-an-item-within-a-list-using-stream-api). I believe, if I have read correctly, that is not possible to find the index of an `int[]` array directly, so the approach must rely upon using a `List<Integer>`, as suggested in the [question referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179001/find-all-the-indexes-of-an-item-within-a-list-using-stream-api).

I made an initial solution using Streams, but was wondering if there was a more efficient approach. I fully admit my understand of streams is limited.

```
public static int[] blackjackByStreams(int[] hands)
{
    // set to an empty array; no winners in this hand
    int[] winningSeats = new int[0];

    // get the maximum that is <= 21
    OptionalInt oi = Arrays.stream(hands).filter(tot -> tot <= 21).max();

    // if there are any hands that are <= 21
    if (oi.isPresent()) {
        // have to make a list (?) 
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(hands)
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // find the location(s) in the list
        winningSeats = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                      .filter(i -> list.get(i) == oi.getAsInt())
                      .toArray();
    }

    return winningSeats;
}
```

The two approaches return the same data, so it is not a question of functionality *per se*. Rather, is there any way to make the `blackjackByStreams` better? Especially, is there a way to eliminate the creation of the `List<Integer> list`?

Edit: I did read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream), in which one answer suggested creating a custom collector. Not sure if that would be the only alternative approach.

Thank you for providing any insight.

Comment: Streams do not, generally speaking, improve efficiency.  Streams will generally be no faster, and often slower, than the same program written out normally.  They're just a library, they're not magic.  Your initial code will be at least as fast and probably faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the simple solution when you have found the maximum element. Just create a Stream over the indexes of the array directly instead of having an intermediate list:

```
public static int[] blackjackByIteration(int[] hands) {
    OptionalInt oi = Arrays.stream(hands).filter(i -> i <= 21).max();
    if (oi.isPresent()) {
        int value = oi.getAsInt();
        return IntStream.range(0, hands.length).filter(i -> hands[i] == value).toArray();
    }
    return new int[0];
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that and received an error, but in thinking about it  probably tried using `Arrays.stream(hands)...` rather than the `IntStream.range(0, hands.length)...`. Large improvement in the conciseness of the method!

Comment: @Holger Not necessarily, the array could have all values greater than 21, so the OptionalInt would be empty. It's unfortunate that there is no `mapToObj` on `OptionalInt` though, otherwise we could have `oi.mapToObj(...).orElseGet(() -> new int[0])`

Comment: Indeed, that’s complicating matter. I should have another coffee… What you could do to avoid the `if` is `int value = oi.orElse(21);` and proceed with the second stream op, which will produce an empty array when there are no matches. I still think, there should be something easier…